# MySql Query Select sum and minimum record for 1 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 1 table , i want  to query for specific column.
   Aa -> is distinct,

Bb -> Sum B Total grouping by Aa,

Cc -> Minimum value C for specific Aa,

Bb1,Dd -> B,D value when C is minimum,

Ee -> distinct

### Table 1

```
id | A | B | C | D | E |
------------------------
1  | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | A |

2  | 2 | 2 | 7 | 0 | A |

3  | 4 | 1 | 7 | 3 | B |

4  | 4 | 0 | 5 | 4 | B |
```

Result

```
Aa | Bb | Cc | Bb1 | Dd | Ee |
-----------------------------
2  | 3  | 2  | 1   | 1  | A  |

4  | 1  | 5  | 0   | 4  | B  |
```

my query give wrong result

```
  SELECT
    test.A as Aa,
    SUM(test.B) as Bb,
    min(test.C) as Cc,
    test.D as Dd,
    test.E as Ee
    FROM `test` 
    group by A,E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      a.A as Aa,
      SUM(a.B) as Bb,
      min(a.C) as Cc,
      b.b B1,
      b.D DD,
      a.E EE
FROM  `Table1` a
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT  a.*
        FROM    table1 a
                INNER JOIN
                (
                  SELECT  A, MIN(C) min_C
                  FROM    table1
                  GROUP   BY A
                ) b ON  a.a = b.a AND a.c = b.min_C
      ) b ON a.a = b.a 
group by a.A, b.b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e2b41/15)

Comment: why do you need to `group by A, E`? what is the difference between the output of my query and your desired output?

Comment: The query gave proper result for the sample data but A and E have  a relation E is City and A is zone id. Zone id is not unique.it is can have same value for diferent city.C is number of accidents. Thanks in Adv.

Comment: how about changing `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`? eg, `SELECT ...FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN (subquery) b .....`

Comment: I still can not get the correct  query , actualy i want to merge 2 queries 

SELECT
  A,
  sum(X.B) AS SUM_B ,
  SUm(X.D) AS SUM_D,
  E
FROM
  Table1 X
group by A,E



SELECT
  A,
  E,
 MIN(X.C) AS SUM_C,
  D ' this gave wrong result value should D value when C is minimum
FROM
  Table1 X
GROUP BY E,A